# How to add values in sql

Tags: sql-server, join

Hey i have a table like this

```
Product_name    Rate    Cost    GST_percentage  Recipt_no   Amount  Final_Amount    ID  Description GST_price   Quantity    OrderID Discount    Net_Unit_Price  Stock_Pending   Payment_Pending
SINGTEL DATA + EZ $10 1.5 GB 7 DAYS 10  120.00  5   1   120.00  126 1   A   6.00    12  ODR1    0.00    10.00   Received    Paid
SINGTEL DATA + EZ $10 1.5 GB 7 DAYS 12  180.00  0   2   180.00  180.00  2   A   0.00    15  ODR2    0.00    12.00   NULL    NULL
SINGTEL DATA + EZ $8 CHINA 888  10  120.00  0   2   120.00  120.00  3   B   0.00    12  ODR2    0.00    10.00   NULL    NULL
```

and i want to show the final_Amount column value groupped by order Id.then i want to show the final_amount for those which is Payment_Pending status is not null but i can't get the correct result.

Note:

i got a result as 
query:

```
SELECT [OrderID], 
       SUM(convert(float,[Final_Amount])) as Final_Amount,
       (select sum(convert(float,Final_Amount)) as Final_Amount  
        from   Purchase_Order 
        where Payment_Pending is not null) as paid  
FROM   [Purchase_Order] 
group by [OrderID] 
order by OrderID desc



OrderID Final_Amount    paid
ODR2    300             126
ODR1    126             126
```

but i want like this

```
OrderID Final_Amount    paid
ODR2    300             0
ODR1    126             126
```

(Because ODR2 Payment_Pending Column filled with null)

Comment: you should post only relevant column of your sample data. Too much unrelated information may confuses readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your sub-query is wrong. It need to include a reference to OrderId of main query

```
SELECT [OrderID], 
       SUM(convert(float,[Final_Amount])) as Final_Amount,
       (select sum(convert(float,Final_Amount)) as Final_Amount  
        from   Purchase_Order x
        where  x.Payment_Pending is not null
        and    x.OrderId = p.OrderId) as paid  
FROM   [Purchase_Order] p
group by [OrderID] 
order by OrderID desc
```